# Login Page for CRM

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

I want to create a web page that can query a Dynamics CRM Online instance based on a specific user.

I want the user to enter the URL of their CRM instance in a textbox then click on a login button. After clicking the login button they will be directed to the CRM login screen. After successfully entering their login credentials that will be directed back to my web page with an authentication token that will be used to query the CRM instance.

How can I do this? This is effectively how Power BI works when using the CRM Connection.

I thought about using Web API to do this but you need to know the client id and set up a client secret. Is there an easier way to achieve the CRM login as I want the website to be simple to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not authenticating against CRM, but against Azure Active Directory. You might want to have a look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675418.aspx

and read up on OAUTH to get to what you are looking for.